# How to group export members in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

In my package, I have multiple dependencies. I am trying to create a single entry point for all dependencies.

**Dependency 1** (Exists in NPM)

```
export interface A {}
export type B = {}
export function C() {}
```

**Dependency 2** (Exists in NPM)

```
export interface A {}
export function B() {}
```

**Entry point** (In my package)

```
export * as dependency1 from "dependency-1"
export * as dependency2 from "dependency-2"
```

I have done this to avoid collision. But, the issue is when I try to access any `type` or `interface`, it doesn't work.

**Consumer**

```
import { dependency1, dependency2 } from "./entry";

// works like a charm
dependency1.C()

// Shows error: "A" is not a property of `dependency1`
const a1: dependency1.A = {...}

// Shows error: "A" is not a property of `dependency2`
const a2: dependency2.A = {...}
```

How do I resolve this? Any other alternative I can try?

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That would work in ESM, so this seems to be an issue specific to TypeScript or (if you're using a bundler) your bundler. What do the module-related parts of your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: Created a new app using `create-react-app`. Added `tsconfig` settings in the question.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. I used `npx create-react-app --template typescript tempcra` to create a project, copied your `tsconfig.json` into it, and added [these three files](https://pastebin.com/TPkTpziv). Then I added `import "./main";` to `App.tsx` and ran it. It output 42 to the console as expected. Sorry not to be able to help! But hopefully that information is of some use.